Jobs highlight in left menu doesn't go away
It doesn't go away no matter how hard I refresh the page.
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?source=so-left-nav


see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399704/known-issues-with-mvp-stack-overflow-jobs-launch#comment1333709_399705 for how to remove this with an adblocker
